# Importing data from sqlite to postgres: easily convert AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I dump my `SQLite` database like this:

```
sqlite3 database.sqlite .dump
```

And this is the relevant part of the dump:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_user(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    org_id INTEGER,
    email CHAR(512) UNIQUE,
    user_doc_id CHAR(128),
    password CHAR(512),
    registration_key CHAR(512),
    reset_password_key CHAR(512),
    registration_id CHAR(512)
);
```

And I have to import this to `postgres`. `Postgres` does not accept `AUTOINCREMENT`, but I need a similar functionality. I want to *automatically* process the `SQLite` dump in order to import it to `postgres`. I have read about `NEXTVAL` and `CREATE_SEQUENCE`, but I can not automate the conversion using that easily

Is there a simple way of `sed`ding the sqlite dump to feed it to postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` with `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`.
Ensure to catch all ways to write it (lowercase, whitespace etc.).

Comment: It should actually be `serial primary key` (serial itself does not define a primary key).